# Get database data with jquery in React from php

Tags: php, jquery, sql, reactjs, oracle

I am working on an app and I am making a select in the database which is Oracle and on the frontend I am using React and jquery.

When I make a get request with jquery to get database data I do not receive anything.

Here is the code:

```
testNode() {
var x = document.getElementById('nume').value;
console.log(x);
var y = document.getElementById('email').value;
console.log(y);

$.get("http://localhost/telefon/raspuns.php?email="+y, function(data, status){
console.log(data);
});

}
```

This is the function in React that i call the database select.

And here is the php script:

```
<?php

if (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_ORIGIN'])) {
header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: {$_SERVER['HTTP_ORIGIN']}");
header('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true');
header('Access-Control-Max-Age: 86400');    // cache for 1 day
}

// Access-Control headers are received during OPTIONS requests
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'OPTIONS') {

if (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_ACCESS_CONTROL_REQUEST_METHOD']))
    header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, POST, OPTIONS");         

if (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_ACCESS_CONTROL_REQUEST_HEADERS']))
    header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers:        
 {$_SERVER['HTTP_ACCESS_CONTROL_REQUEST_HEADERS']}");

 exit(0); 
 }

 //echo $_GET['email'];

 $servername="(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=xxx)(PORT=xxx)) 
 (CONNECT_DATA=(SERVER=dedicated)(SERVICE_NAME=xxx)))";
 $conn = oci_connect("xxx","xxx",$servername);

 if (!$conn) {
   $m = oci_error();
   echo $m['message'], "\n";
   exit;
   }

 $statement = "select cnp, nume, prenume from xxx where 
upper(email)='".$_GET['email']."'";
$stid = oci_parse($conn, $statement);
oci_execute($stid);



while (($row = oci_fetch_array($stid, OCI_NUM)) != false) {
  echo $row[0];
  echo $row[1];     
} 

echo $row;

?>
```

Can you please tell me what to modify in my php code to get the data from the oracle db to the front end and use it. Thanks a lot

Comment: Your code is wide open to SQL injection. I would also advise not to use a frontend framework such as React in combination with jQuery. At last, you can add a error handler for your AJAX call. This will make you receive at least an error message that can help you further. If you made that edit and have an error, please post it here as well :)

Comment: I agree: use bind variables to avoid SQL injection.  Check the [OCI8 manual](https://www.php.net/manual/book.oci8.php) and [The Underground PHP and Oracle Manual](https://www.oracle.com/database/technologies/underground-php-oracle-manual.html).  For your specific problem, add some logging to check your DB code is working.  Then debug in the JS what is being received.